# dom-if doesn't get updated in dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, templates, polymer, polymer-1.0

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{fruit_list}}" as="fruit">
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{fruit.isOrange}}">
        I'm an orange!
    </template>
</template>
```

Here I have a `dom-if` template inside a `dom-repeat` template. It works great if the value of `fruit.isOrange` has already been finalized. However if not, for example, it was `true` when before but now I change it to `false`, it will remain showing the "I'm an orange!" message.

Shouldn't it be updated automatically? Or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stand to be corrected, but I think the problem is in your **dom-repeat** not getting notified, causing **dom-if** to not update also.

You can use `this.set('fruit_list.1.isOrange', 'true');` which works for your example.

From Polymer documentation:

> **set(path, value, root)** - Convienence method for setting a value to a path and notifying any elements bound to the same path.

http://polymer.github.io/polymer/